# f.collection_select won't submit a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to submit a RoR Form.  Strong Params are fine as I'm not getting a `not permitted` message in the logs.  For some reason, I keep getting a `this field cannot be blank` error message for the below field. The logs say the `client_name` field is blank even though I've selected something. There's a has-many/belongs-to relationship between `designer` & `client-folder`.

When I choose one of the existing `client_folder` from the dropdown and press submit, it gives the error message.  If I use a `text field` and simply type a name, it works fine, so I believe it's just something with `collection_select`.  Where am I going wrong?

```
<%= form_for([@designer, @client_folder]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :client_name, current_designer.client_folders, :id, :client_name, {}, {id: "existing-list", required: true} %>  
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is that empty hash for?

Comment: The error is pretty clear that your form is sending blank data, maybe debug your controller action and check the `params` value? Also, I don't see what data values are available for your select, I see that you're selecting `:id` as the value and `:client_name` as the display name. What are the selections?